# Stacked reference/dereference symbols

Tags: reference, rust

Let's have an enum for lambda terms:

```
#[deriving(Show, Clone, Eq, PartialEq)]
enum Term {
    Var(uint),
    App(Box<Term>, Box<Term>),
    Lam(uint, Box<Term>)
}
```

I wrote the simplest recursive function I could think of:

```
fn size(t: &Term) -> uint {
    match *t {
        Var(_) => 1,
        App(ref f, ref x) => 1 + size(&**f) + size(&**x),
        Lam(_, ref t) => 1 + size(&**t)
    }
}
```

Are the `&**`-s unavoidable here? I find three operators in such a simple case to be a bit much. Also, if I want mutation the recursive calls become `&mut**x`, which is even more of a mouthful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `box` operator can be used to destructure Boxes<sup>1</sup>. So this will work (the `ref` helps avoid a move and conveniently makes it into an `&Term`:

```
fn size(t: &Term) -> uint {
    match *t {
        Var(_) => 1,
        App(box ref f, box ref x) => 1 + size(f) + size(x),
        Lam(_, box ref t) => 1 + size(t)
    }
}

#[deriving(Show, Clone, Eq, PartialEq)]
enum Term {
    Var(uint),
    App(Box<Term>, Box<Term>),
    Lam(uint, Box<Term>)
}
```

([playpen](http://is.gd/6muQjR))

<sup>1. There are plans to make it more generic over deferenceable types</sup>